# Beginner needing help sorting an array and with calculations

Tags: c++, arrays, definition

I am having trouble sorting my array and finding code for the calculations with the data from the input file. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have scoured the internet and am still having loads of trouble.

The array is reading a data.txt file with 1,000 numbers in it. The array is supposed to read only 100 of those numbers randomly, and perform the calculation on that trial result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// Declare global constants
const char* IN_FILE_NAME = "stats.txt";
const char* OUT_FILE_NAME = "results.txt";
const int ELEMENTS = 100;

// Function Prototypes

double findMean(double* elementArray, int ELEMENTS);     // sum of numbers / how many numbers
double findMedian(double* elementArray, int ELEMENTS);    // middle number
double findMinimum(double* elementArray, int ELEMENTS);    //smallest number in the array
double findMaximum(double* elementArray, int ELEMENTS);     //largest number in the array
double findStdDev(double* elementArray, int ELEMENTS);       // sqrt( Sum * | x - mean |^2 ) / number of arrays
bool getTrialElements(std::ifstream& inFile, double* elementArray, int ELEMENTS);
double printTrialResults(std::ofstream& outFile, int trialNumber, double elementArray[], int ELEMENTS);  //print to output file
void sortArray();

// This program performs basic statistics on a large set of data points
int main()
{
    // Declare variables
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    int trialNumber = 0;
    double elementArray[ELEMENTS];

    // Open input and output files
    inFile.open(IN_FILE_NAME);
    outFile.open(OUT_FILE_NAME);

    // Loop through all of the data sets in the input file
    while(getTrialElements(inFile, elementArray, ELEMENTS))
    {
        // Keep track of the number of data sets processed
        trialNumber++;
        // Output the results to the output file
        printTrialResults(outFile, trialNumber, elementArray, ELEMENTS);
    }

    // Close input and output files
    outFile.close();
    inFile.close();

    return 0;
}

// Function definitions
double findMean(double elementArray[], int ELEMENTS)
    //Find the mean of the array
    {
        double sum = 0;

        for(int ELEMENT = 0; ELEMENT < 100, ELEMENT++)
        {
            sum = sum + elementArray[ELEMENT];
        }
        return sum / ELEMENTS;
    }

double findMedian(double elementArray[], int ELEMENTS)
    {

    }

double findMinimum(double elementArray[], int ELEMENTS)
    {

    }

double findMaximum(double elementArray[], int ELEMENTS)
    {

    }

double findStdDev(double elementArray[], int ELEMENTS)
    {

    }

bool getTrialElements(std::ifstream& inFile, double* elementArray, int ELEMENTS)
    {
        //Read inFile in to elementArray

        //for ELEMENTS

        //if can't read or no more elements to read, return false, else return true

        while(getTrialElements(inFile, elementArray, ELEMENTS))
        {
            if(ELEMENTS < 99)
            {
                cout << "No more elements available." << endl;
            }

            return 0;
        }


    }

double printTrialResults(std::ofstream& outFile, int trialNumber, double elementArray[], int ELEMENTS)
    {
            //
    }
void sortArray()
    {

    }
```

Comment: so you searched the whole internet and found no way of sorting an array of primitive numbers? ok :D

Comment: Your question is too broad. Delete/comment out code until you have something that compiles and runs, then start adding things back in. Deal with one problem at a time.

Answer (score 0):

ok, if it is only about sorting, than c++11 have some tools.

1. `std::begin` and `std::end` works with arrays
2. `std::sort` does all other work

So:

```
 int array[ELEMENTS]; // look for std::array<int, ELEMENTS>

 ... // fill array with values

 std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array)); // sort full array
```

read about:

1. [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)
2. [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)
3. [std::qsort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort)

for raw pointers:

```
void sortArray(int *begin, size_t size) 
{
  std::sort(begin, begin + size);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP is not allowed to use the STL, anyway that will not work inside the `sortArray` function if the arrays decays into a pointer.

Comment: I appreciated the answer! I have not covered std::sort for arrays, so I do not believe I can use it.

Comment: if he not allowed, why would he write `using namespace std;` Anyway  std::qsort from C can be used

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some kind of a homework so it is probably better to not give you an entire implementation but I'll give you some tips.
I'm assuming that you are not too familiar with sorting algorithms so consider looking at `bubbleSort`, `selectionSort` and `insertionSort` instead of using something built in the language.
After sorting your data finding the median can be accomplished by returning the element at the middle(the 50th element for 100 element array).
Maximums and minimums can be found from the sorted array also(1st and last element) or you can choose an element to be your min/max element than comparing it with all of the other elements. If the element value is less/more than the value you picked then change the picked value to the value of the element.

```
int min = arr[0];
for(int i = 0;i < SIZE ;i++){
   if(min > arr[i]){
   min = arr[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have no clue what the sorts are, but I will be doing my research and hopefully will find the answer. This isn't for homework, I am just trying to do a lot of projects to help myself understand the language (I heard it's the hardest). So I'm starting here to make sure I have a thorough understanding of all concepts.

Comment: Bubble and Insert Sort are the slowest but easiest to understand.

Merge Sort is in the middle, it's easy to comprehend too. Sort each half, then keep taking the lowest value from either half until there's none left. The output list is the full sorted list. You can initially use Bubble Sort to make the sorted halves to get merge sort working. Then later you rewrite it to use merge sort on the halves themselves, and make it recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Iterative development:

Start by making an array to hold all 1000 numbers, then read the file into that array and print them out from the array.

Then, in a 100-times for loop, roll random numbers from 0 to 999, and put the relevant value into your smaller array. You'll need to have some checking that the same value is never taken twice. You can make an array of 1000 bools "value_used" and set them to true if a particular input was used, use a while loop to re-roll if you get the same one twice.

After you have your 100 in an array, you want to sort it. Bubble Sort is the most basic type of sort, move through the list (0:99 range) from 0 to 98. Look at each adjacent pair of values, and swap the highest one to the right. This causes the highest value to "percolate" to the top in a single pass. You then do a 2nd pass, but stopping one short, a third pass stopping 2 short, and so on, until you're just comparing the value a 0 with that at 1.

But Bubble Sort is very slow. Another easy to understand type of sort is Merge Sort. In Merge Sort, you split e.g. your 100 numbers into two lots of 50, you then sort each set of 50 (which could be via Bubble Sort or Merge Sort itself). Then, make two indexes pointing at the start of each sorted half. Whichever one is lower, move that to the output and advance that index. The result is one pass through the data that outputs all 100 numbers sorted.

Merge Sort can be completely implemented in place, with value swaps. Or you can just make another array and fill that up, which avoids the overhead of swapping values around unnecessarily.

BTW with Bubble Sort on 100 items you end up comparing approximately 100 x 100 / 2 = 5000 compares. With Merge Sort, merging the final list (100 items) took 100 compares, merging the halves (2x50) also took 100, quarters (4x25) took another 100, 8ths (8x~12.5) took 100, 16ths (16x~6.25) took 100, 32nds (32x~3.125) took 100. Below that you hit the cut-off point where splitting the 32nds would give 64ths which are only 1-2 elements, so it's quicker to bubble sort the values once they're down to size 3-4, giving another 100 compares or so.

The rule here is that merge sort works in O(n * log-n) time. Since 2^7 = 128, Merge Sort will sort 100 values in about 100 * 7 = 700 compares.